# How to avoid rounding numbers in MS Access 2007-2013?

Tags: microsoft-office, microsoft-access, microsoft-access-2007, microsoft-access-2010

I have an MS Access 2007-2013 database (.accdb format) which I open in MS Access 2013. It has just one table with several columns

```
Lat          Long       PositionDate    
-54.82045   -68.33834   20130825    
-54.82018   -68.33854   20130827    
-54.81958   -68.33004   20130102
```

My goal is to convert this MS Access table to a text file in comma separating format. I go to External data tab > Export section > Text file. I don't specify any export options and click OK. I choose the file to be Delimited > click Next > Choose Comma > click Finish.

However, in the result .txt file I get the lat and long fields rounded to two decimals. I have looked over cell settings in Access but with no success. How do I avoid this rounding?

```
-54.82,-68.33,"20130825"    
-54.82,-68.33,"20130827"    
-54.81,-68.33,"20130102"    
-54.81,-68.33,"20130202"
```

Comment: Have you tried changing the definition of the field from general to fixed with 5 decimal places?

Comment: @JulianKnight, I have just tried this but it didn't help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, the only way to change that (rather annoying) behaviour in Access is to open the "Regional and Language Options" in the Windows Control Panel, click the "Customize this format..." button on the "Formats" tab, then change the "No. of digits after decimal" value on the "Numbers" tab:

[image: NumbersTab.png]

`2` is a very common default value. In the above dialog I have changed it to `5`.